Positioning specific ngx-slider legends in different positions
I'm using ngx-slider, and say I have two legends on the first and last values, like so:
  sliderOptionsTP1 {
      floor: 0,
      ceil: 10,
      showTicks: true,
      stepsArray: [
        { value: 0, legend: 'No electrical safety round/check conducted' },
        { value: 1 },
        { value: 2 },
        { value: 3 },
        { value: 4 },
        { value: 5 },
        { value: 6 },
        { value: 7 },
        { value: 8 },
        { value: 9 },
        { value: 10, legend: 'Electrical safety round/check are conducted at EACH office and other manned buildings at least once a month' }
      ]
    };

And this is the HTML code:
<div class="field col-12 md:col-6 opu-ngx-slider">
                 <ngx-slider id="opu_input_TP1" [(value)]="data[15].value" [options]="sliderOptionsTP1"></ngx-slider>
</div>

The issue is that the legend text on the right overflows into the div next to it. Is there a way to transform only the rightmost legend using CSS, so that I can move it more to the left and prevent overflow?
Thank you.

It would be helpful if you could provide a minimal reproducible example that shows the problem or error you're encountering, ideally in an online code editor like Stackblitz.
